# Youtube API - no channel name

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to retrieve my Youtube channel name using Youtube data API but I'm getting empty item. I have a channel in my Youtube account so it should return one.

These are the query properties I entered -

```
part:'contentDetails', forUsername: 'Seong+Lee',
```

to get the following response from their interactive [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) page.

```
200 OK
- SHOW HEADERS -
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"fpJ9onbY0Rl_LqYLG6rOCJ9h9N8/C3QZ-VsykvkpW2zCm7VjGBCayqc\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 0,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
 ]
}
```

In my app I get the same response so I figured there is no issue with my request code. Why can't I get the channel name?

Comment: What's the link to your channel?

Comment: @not_a_bot https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwy6X3JB24VTsDFqMwdO5Jg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can retrieve your `contentDetails` by using your channel ID.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&id=UCwy6X3JB24VTsDFqMwdO5Jg&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Your username is apparently not valid.

Answer (score 4):

As it looks like your channel does not have a legacy custom URL, you are not able to use the `forUsername` parameter. This parameter only works with `/user/{channelname}` URL's. In this case, it means you have to work with your channel ID which you can find over [here](https://www.youtube.com/account_advanced).

In order to get the display name of your channel, you need the `snippet` part instead of the contentDetails.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id=UCwy6X3JB24VTsDFqMwdO5Jg&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

You will then receive display name of the channel as `snippet.title`

```
{
    kind: "youtube#channelListResponse",
    etag: ""0KG1mRN7bm3nResDPKHQZpg5-do/L4uU6pmZJ1wQKdGUwnnigYpSEVo"",
    pageInfo: {
        totalResults: 1,
        resultsPerPage: 1
    },
    items: [
    {
        kind: "youtube#channel",
        etag: ""0KG1mRN7bm3nResDPKHQZpg5-do/GKVRHf7CLp-mUGFTR_3wbc5Lq-k"",
        id: "UCwy6X3JB24VTsDFqMwdO5Jg",
        snippet: {
            title: "Seong Lee",

...
```

Comment: How can I receive the user id UCwy6X3JB24VTsDFqMwdO5Jg, before getting the playlist details?

Answer (score 0):

If you are authenticate your app using google's oauth2 then you can include the mine parameter and set it to true in your request to recieve your own channel. Check the [common use cases here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) for more info.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64295429/9494364)