# How do I find a users YouTube channel from OAuth client authentication?

Tags: javascript, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-js-client

For the app I'm building I want the end user to login using `gapi` `OAuth2` and
from there I want the app to look for a playlist on their YouTube channel
and load it.

The `getAuthInstance` method returns an object with a Google username. However
for my own particular username, a query to find channel id by username
returns no results. From some [browsing online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294552/youtube-api-no-channel-name/), this is apparently an issue
with certain YouTube accounts.

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a valid OAuth 2.0 authentication/authorization (for example, obtained by using `GAPI`), then it's quite simple the determine the authenticated user's channel ID using the [`Channels.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) API endpoint queried with the parameter `mine=true`:

> [`mine`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#mine) (boolean)
> This parameter can only be used in a properly [authorized request](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication). Set this parameter's value to true to instruct the API to only return channels owned by the authenticated user.

Upon invoking the endpoint, the property [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#id) of the returned [`Channels` resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#resource-representation) contains the channel ID of the authenticated user.

---

For what concerns a Javascript `GAPI` (i.e. Google’s Client Library for Browser-side JavaScript) implementation, the code would look like shown below (for a broader context look into this sample source file from Google: [`analytics_codelab.js`](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/javascript/analytics_codelab.js)):

```
var channelId;

function loadAPIClientInterfaces() {
  gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
    getUserChannel();
  });
}

function getUserChannel() {
  var request = gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
    part: 'id',
    fields: 'items(id)',
    mine: true
  });
  request.execute(function(response) {
    if ('error' in response) {
      displayMessage(response.error.message);
    } else {
      channelId = response.items[0].id;
    }
  });
}
```

Note that the code above (unlike that in `analytics_codelab.js`) uses the [`fields`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#fields) request parameter for to obtain from the `Channels.list` endpoint only the channel's ID info (it is always good to ask from the API only the info that is of actual use).

Comment: Great stuff. Thanks for this