# How to get YouTube channel info from google oath2 authorisation

Tags: youtube-api

When I implemented Oath2 authentication for my application, it gave me a lot of information (eg name, id_token,email etc for a user).However, I want to use the google v3 API to be able to access the statistics of said user's YouTube channel (for example, getting the number of subscribers). Is there any way I could possibly this using the info granted through login.

Edit: I am interested in a users channellid or something similar that would let me access the statistics of a users channel.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. You may take the [tour]; then do read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic).

Comment: Which user statistics are you interested in? Please be more specific. (Name, tokens and email are not a user's statistics data.)

Comment: This is the answer your question: [How do I find a users YouTube channel from Google gapi client authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64295394/how-do-i-find-a-users-youtube-channel-from-google-gapi-client-authentication). Only that for to obtain all channel's available info, you would have to *not use the `fields` parameter* at all.